# The derivative of $2^{x+1}$ in the point $-3$

Tags: limits, derivatives

They ask me to compute the derivative of $2^{x+1}$ in the point $-3$. Since the function is continous in that point, all I have to do is to compute the lateral derivatives. The left one first:

$$\lim_{x \to -3^-} \frac{2^{x+1} - \frac{1}{4}}{x+3}$$

I've tried to solve this limit using this formula:

$$\frac{a^{u(x)} - 1}{u(x)} = \ln{a}$$
But the result seems to be incorrect. How should I solve that limit?

Comment: Note that $2^{x+1} = \exp((x+1)\cdot\ln 2)$ and use commonly known derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to -3^-} \frac{2^{x+1} - \frac{1}{4}}{x+3} = \lim_{x \to -3^-} \frac{2^{x+1}\frac{2^2}{2^2} - \frac{1}{4}}{x+3} = \lim_{x \to -3^-} \frac{\frac{2^{x+3}}{4} - \frac{1}{4}}{x+3} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{x \to -3^-} \frac{2^{x+3}- 1}{x+3} = \frac{1}{4}\ln{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$2^{x+1} = \exp((x+1)\cdot\ln2)\\
\frac d{dx}2^{x+1} = \ln 2 \exp((x+1)\cdot \ln2) = 2^{x+1} \cdot \ln 2$$
And thus
$$\left. \frac d{dx} 2^{x+1} \right|_{x=-3} = 2^{-2} \cdot \ln2 = \frac{\ln 2}4$$
If you want to show it using the limit, you now have the result to cross-check, or just refer to other answers given.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{2^{x+1}-2^{-2}}{x+3}=2^{-2}\frac{2^{x+3}-1}{x+3} \to 2^{-2} \log 2
$$
as $x \to -3$.